# Get the text between first occurrence of two patterns with sed

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a `CHANGELOG.md` file from which I want to get the unreleased section text with help of sed command.
My file has a structure like this:

```
[Changelog]
============

## [Unrelease]

## Added
- Text1

## Fixed
- Text2

## [5.0.0]

## Added
- Text3

## [4.0.0]

## Fixed
- Text4
```

In this case, the desired output is:

```
## Added
- Text1

## Fixed
- Text2
```

My idea is to get the text somehow with `sed` between the first line that start with `## [Unreleased]` and the fisrt line which start with `## [a number`.

Do you know how can do such thing with `sed`? 
Or is there a better way for doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an address range to implement your idea with sed, but it'll also include the section lines. They can easily be trimmed out, though:

```
$ sed -n '/^## \[Unrelease\]/,/^## \[[0-9]/p; /^## \[[0-9]/q' input.txt | sed '1d;$d'

## Added
- Text1

## Fixed
- Text2
```

(This does assume that the unreleased bit comes before any numbered section, like in your example, because it stops processing after the first numbered one for efficiency's sake)

Answer (score 1):

The task is certainly better carried out with awk

```
awk '
  /## \[Unrelease\]/{flag=1;next}
  /## \[[0-9]/{flag=0}
  flag                            #Prints the line if flag!=0
' file
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n '/^## \[Unrelease\]/{n;:a;n;/^## \[[0-9]/q;p;ba}' file
```

Turn off implicit printing `-n`.

On encountering a line beginning `## [Unrelease]` , throwaway that line and the next and print further lines until a line beginning `## [` followed by an integer, and then quit.

Answer (score 1):

using `awk`

`awk  '/\[Unrelease\]/,/[0-9]/'`

Demo:

```
$cat file.txt 
[Changelog]
============

## [Unrelease]

## Added
- Text1

## Fixed
- Text2

## [5.0.0]

## Added
- Text3

## [4.0.0]

## Fixed
- Text48,2524
8,1215
-9,25%
-5,32%
$awk  '/\[Unrelease\]/,/[0-9]/'  <  file.txt
## [Unrelease]

## Added
- Text1
$
```